# Entity Framework storing collection size in 1-* relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, model, repository

I'm creating a forum website. More for a learning project than anything else.

My database is fairly simple: a `Board` has many `Thread`, and a `Thread` has many `Post`. So my domain objects look like this:

```
public class Board
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Thread> Threads { get; set; }
}

public class Thread
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int BoardId { get; set; }
    public virtual Board Board { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
}
```

I want my Board ViewModel to look like this:

```
public class BoardViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ThreadCount { get; set; }
    // Date of the latest post.
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: My View will use an `IEnumerable<BoardViewModel>`. I don't need to use the `Post` or `Thread` collections directly.

Creating this view model when using the DbContext object directly is easy, but I don't know what to do if I want to refactor this behind a repository.

I know that returning a view model from the data layer is a bad idea, but just returning a board object would mean the Threads and Posts collections aren't initialized.

Should I just include the collections in the database query (which sounds expensive), or should I include the information in the `Board` class? Or are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

That depend what you are going to do in your view, if you are going to use the collection of `Threads`   in your view, then you need to load them before use it. In my humble opinion, to achieve the escenario that you want, you should disable lazy loading, wich is the default behavior. It can be turned off for all entities in the context by setting a flag on the `Configuration` property:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext 
{ 
  public YourContext() 
  { 
     this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
  } 
}
```

Then, you could load the navigation properties by demand in your queries using, for example, one of these extension methods:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> Includes<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, params string[] includeProperties)
    {
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludesWithFunc<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
}
```

To give you some examples, if you need to load the boards with their `Threads` to create your ViewModel instances, you could do this:

```
db.Boards.IncludesWithFunc(b=>b.Threads);
```

Or this:

```
 db.Boards.Includes("Threads");
```

And if you need to load another level, then you could do this:

```
db.Boards.IncludesWithFunc(b=>b.Threads.Select(t=>t.Posts));
```

Or this:

```
 db.Boards.Includes("Threads.Posts");
```

If you are using a Generic Repository, you can adapt those methods in your class, for example:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
    //...
    public  IQueryable<TEntity> IncludesWithFunc<TEntity>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> queryable = _dbSet;
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }

}
```

Using a class like this you can do something like this in your Business Layer (where I guess you are creating the ViewModel instances):

```
var rep=new Repository<Board>();
var someBoard=rep.IncludesWithFunc(b=>b.Threads).FirstOrDefault(b=>b.Name="SomeName");
```

Comment: Indeed this was my initial solution - it's what I was getting at with "Should I just include the collections in the database query". My concern is that is was an expensive query to run on each request.

I don't actually want to do anything with the `Thread` or `Post` collections, the thread count and updated date are just for display. My View Model is `BoardViewModel` but view will actually use `IEnumerable<BoardViewModel>`.

Comment: Well, in case you don't want to eager load that collections because you don't use them in your view, you don't need to use the methods that I share with you. If you don't call the Includes extension methods, your queries would be translated to sql in a simpler form. where they will not apply joins between the tables, so it would not be so expensive